# Display Customer Groups Dropdown in admin system configurations in custom module of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer-group, system.xml, system-configuration

I want to provide customer group based configuration in my custom group. So need to add customer group multiselect dropdown in system configuration at admin in Magento 2.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code which I have used in my custom module. Hope this will also help you.

1. Add below code in `Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` file.

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="custom_tab" translate="label" sortOrder="300">
        <label>Custom Tab</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="custom_section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Custom Module</label>
        <tab>custom_tab</tab>
        <resource>Vendor_Module::custommodule</resource>
        <group id="custom" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Custom Options</label>
            <field id="customer_group_list" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Customer Groups</label>
                <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Customer\Group</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

2. Create `Vendor\Module\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Customer\Group.php` file and add below code in it.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Customer;

class Group implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
protected $_options; 

public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory)
{
    $this->_groupCollectionFactory = $groupCollectionFactory;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    if (!$this->_options) {
        $this->_options = $this->_groupCollectionFactory->create()->loadData()->toOptionArray();
    }
    return $this->_options;
}
}
```

[image]

This item is saved as CSV, so in your Helper or Model you need to convert this to an array, with the following code:

```
        $enabledCustomerGroupsCsv = $this->scopeConfig
              ->getValue('custom_section/custom/customer_group_list');

        // If any groups have been configured
        if ($enabledCustomerGroupsCsv) {
            // Convert CSV into array
            $enabledCustomerGroupIds = explode(',', $enabledCustomerGroupsCsv);

            // Your code here
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! For me it works on Magento 2.3.6-p1. I've added some steps to the answer on how to retrieve the configured value.

Answer (score 1):

Without creating a new `source_model`

1. Add the below code in `MagePal/Test/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` file.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>    
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
   <system>
    ...
    <section id="custom_section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        ...
        <group id="custom" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Custom Options</label>
            <field id="customer_group_list" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Customer Groups</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Source\Group</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
   ```